# SqlCommand SQL insert with ExecuteNonQuery inserting 2 rows

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

I have a button in a table that calls an insert statement,

```
private void bttnEnroll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            string className;
            string section;

            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-7S08N90;Initial Catalog=UniversityDB;Integrated Security=True");
            try
            {
                DataRowView row = (DataRowView)((Button)e.Source).DataContext;
                className = row[0].ToString();
                section = row[1].ToString();

                if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    sqlCon.Open();

                //SQL query
                String query = "INSERT INTO Takes (studentID, className, section, semester, year, time, grade) " +
                               "SELECT @studentID, className, section, @semester, @year, time, @grade " +
                               "FROM Section " +
                               "WHERE className=@className " +
                               "AND section=@section";
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", this.studentID);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@className", className);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", section);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", this.semester);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", this.year);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grade", "N/A");

                int rowsAffected = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowsAffected == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Class enrolled.");
                }
                else if (rowsAffected > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("More than 1 row affected");
                } else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Class not enrolled.");
                }
                sqlCmd.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) //if SQL server connection fails
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString() + ". Class failed to enroll.");
            }
            finally
            {

                sqlCon.Close();
            }
}
```

Initally I thought I might be executing the statement twice somewhere, but I set a breakpoint on

```
int rowsAffected = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and it returns 2. Checking the database reveals that 2 rows with duplicate data are inserted, when I only want 1.

full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace UniversityDBInterface
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Results.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Results : Window
    {
        int studentID;
        string semester;
        string year;
        int deptID;
        int courseNum;
        string comparison;
        Boolean days;
        Boolean open;
        public Results(String semester, String year, int deptID, int courseNum, String comparison,
                        Boolean days, Boolean open, int studentID)
        {
            //init
            InitializeComponent();
            this.studentID = studentID;
            this.semester = semester;
            this.year = year; //TODO: ? not sure if this is necessary in our implementation
            this.deptID = deptID; //TODO
            this.courseNum = courseNum; //TODO
            this.comparison = comparison; //TODO
            this.days = days; //TODO
            this.open = open; //TODO

            //SQL
            ResultsList();

        }

        private void ResultsList()
        {
            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-7S08N90;Initial Catalog=UniversityDB;Integrated Security=True");
            try
            {
                if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    sqlCon.Open();
                //SQL query
                String query = "SELECT className AS [Class Name], section AS Section, room AS Room " +
                               "FROM Section " +
                               "WHERE semester=@Semester ";
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Semester", this.semester);
                //sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Year", this.year);

                //Execute command and fill table with data
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
                SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(table);


                ResultsDataGrid.ItemsSource = table.DefaultView;
                ResultsDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                ResultsDataGrid.CanUserAddRows = false;
                ResultsDataGrid.CanUserSortColumns = true;

                sqlCmd.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) //if SQL server connection fails
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }

        private void bttnLogout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Login login = new Login();
            login.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void bttnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(studentID, semester, year);
            mainWindow.Show();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void preqCheck(SqlConnection con)
        {
            //TODO
        }

        private void bttnEnroll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string className;
            string section;

            SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-7S08N90;Initial Catalog=UniversityDB;Integrated Security=True");
            try
            {
                DataRowView row = (DataRowView)((Button)e.Source).DataContext;
                className = row[0].ToString();
                section = row[1].ToString();

                if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    sqlCon.Open();

                preqCheck(sqlCon);

                //SQL query
                String query = "INSERT INTO Takes (studentID, className, section, semester, year, time, grade) " +
                               "SELECT @studentID, className, section, @semester, @year, time, @grade " +
                               "FROM Section " +
                               "WHERE className=@className " +
                               "AND section=@section";
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentID", this.studentID);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@className", className);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@section", section);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@semester", this.semester);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", this.year);
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grade", "N/A");

                int rowsAffected = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rowsAffected == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Class enrolled.");
                }
                else if (rowsAffected > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("More than 1 row affected");
                } else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Class not enrolled.");
                }
                sqlCmd.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) //if SQL server connection fails
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString() + ". Class failed to enroll.");
            }
            finally
            {

                sqlCon.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the select statement you're inserting from is grabbing two rows.  Try fixing that, not the insert.  You could hack this (not recommended) by doing `SELECT TOP 1`.  Also, don't use `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Two tables with essentially the same layout is a bad design when all you need is another column to indicate ...whatever the difference is (if they took it?  what year?).  It does away with the need for code like that entirely

Comment: @Zer0 Ah, yeah. Thanks. I thought that className and section would be unique, but it turns out that's not the case. appreciated

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp, I'm aware, the tables are still being sorted out but a demo needs to be done so I have to work with what I've got. I'll be sure to bring it up with the group.

Comment: It seems that you have known what your problem is. The problem is that classname and section may not be unique. If possible, you can make an answer and mark it as answer so that other people can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[Zer0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3980331/zer0)'s answer:

> Looks like the select statement you're inserting from is grabbing two rows. Try fixing that, not the insert. You could hack this (not recommended) by doing SELECT TOP 1. Also, don't use AddWithValue.

className and section were not sufficient to be a unique identifier.